# TWRP failed to install ZIP for Lineage 16 Samsung Galaxy Note 2 GT-N7100 (t03g)

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, lineageos, system-error, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I tried to flash the ROM for Lineage 16 to my Samsung Note 2 N7100 (t03g) with TWRP custom bootloader, but  there was an error which was:

```
Installing zip file '/sdcard/lineage-16-20200104-UNOFFICIAL-n7100.zip'
Checking for Digest file...
Unmounting System...
Warning: No file_contexts
Target: samsung/t03gxx/t03g:4.3/JSS15J/N71000XXUEMK4:user/release-keys
detected filesystem ext4 for /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
Patching system image unconditionally...
mkdir "/cache/recovery/8833b259bb088b2e13f62771d46006a40f54bc20/" failed: No such file or directory
E1001: Failed to update system image.
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/lineage-16-20200104-UNOFFICIAL-n7100.zip'
Updating partition details...
...done
```

What I've tried to solve the problem were:

- unzipping and rezipping the file
- deleting the assert lines in /META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
- rezipping after deleting asserts

They still failed to fix the error. In between attempts I've wiped the cache, Dalvik, system, data as normal. Since ERROR: 7 is a very general problem, I think the problem is on line `mkdir "/cache/recovery/8833b259bb088b2e13f62771d46006a40f54bc20/" failed: No such file or directory` but for the life of me can't figure out what it means. I'm certain that mkdir is supposed to create a new directory from scratch, so I find the "No such file or directory" very odd.

I'm using [Comico Team's custom ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-2/development/rom-lineageos-16-0-20190112-comico-t3889281/) and TWRP version 3.4.0. At first I did want to ask over there but the creators seemed to be unresponsive. So, anyone here know how to fix this?

Comment: check */cache/recovery* is directory

Comment: I opened an issue with LineageOS as this looks like an installer bug to me. Hope its okay I referenced your information there: https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/2657

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in TWRP go to advanced > terminal, then create /cache/recovery with

```
mkdir /cache/recovery
```

solved the problem for me

Comment: You sir deserve a medal, or beer or coffe, whatever you fancy! You just saved my day! Such a simple solution to a problem I first feared to have bricked my device.

Comment: Thank you so much!